# Ionic 4: How to set border to the selected ion-tab-button?

Tags: ionic4, ionic-tabs

I tried applying the following css but didn't work.

***.scss**

```
ion-tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
   border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

***.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="schedule">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    ...
    <ion-tab-button tab="about">
      <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>About</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that applying the `box-shadow` instead of `border` worked.

```
ion-tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 blue inset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ion-segment like this. It will look like a tab button.

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment>
      <ion-segment-button value="all" checked>
        All
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="favorites">
        Favorites
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```